# Titanium appcelerator upload recorded video to server

Tags: appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile

On my Appcelerator titanium mobile project i have to record video and upload this to our server. Recording is not difficult for me, it's quite easy, and i could return the video url properly from :

```
Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, 'myVideo.mp4');
```

so i can get native path :

```
myVideoPath =  f.nativePath;
```

From there i don't know how to upload the file, for an image i just base64 the blob, but for a video file how can handle this?

Thanks for your precious help.

Answer (score 3):

With a normal XHR request:

```
var f = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.externalStorageDirectory, "video.mp4");

var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
xhr.onload = function(e) {
    // done
};
xhr.open('POST', 'http://server/upload.php');
xhr.onsendstream = function(e) {
    console.log( Math.floor(e.progress * 100) + "%");
};
xhr.send({
    file: f
});
```

Then it depends on your server architecture.

With php it would be something like

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['video_path']['tmp_name'], "test.mp4")) {
    return "success";
} else{
    return "falied!";
}
```

Comment: On older Androids (e.g. Samsung Galaxy S4) this fails with "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError" for files larger than 10 MB.